# C++ Read certain integers from file as from VB6

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to extract some integers from a file using C++, but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

My code in VB6 is the following:

```
Redim iInts(240) As Integer
Open "m:\dev\voice.raw" For Binary As #iFileNr
Get #iReadFile, 600, iInts() 'Read from position 600 and read 240 bytes
```

My conversion to C++ is the following:

```
vector<int>iInts
iInts.resize(240)

FILE* m_infile;
string filename="m://dev//voice.raw";

if (GetFileAttributes(filename.c_str())==INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
{
  printf("wav file not found");
  DebugBreak();
} 
else 
{
  m_infile = fopen(filename.c_str(),"rb");
}
```

But now I don't know how to continue from there, and I also don't know if "rb" is correct.

Comment: i'd suggest using C++ I/O streams rather than low-level API, there are several overloads of operator >> which make it pretty easy to extract values of basic data types

Comment: There's a lot of Windows-specific API stuff in your code. Adding tag.

Comment: The comment on that VB statement seems a touch off. Is it reading 240 *bytes* or 240 *integers* (or perhaps 240 8-bit integers??) To know how to get out what is written you're going to have to know how it was written in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how VB reads a file but if you need to read integers from a file try:

```
m_infile = fopen(myFile, "rb")
fseek(m_infile, 600 * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
// Read the ints, perhaps using fread(...)
fclose(myFile);
```

Or you can use the C++ way using **ifstream**.

Full example with streams (note, you should add error checking):

```
#include <ifstream>

void appendInts(const std::string& filename, 
                unsigned int byteOffset, 
                unsigned int intCount,
                const vector<int>& output)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::base::in | std::ios::base::binary);
    ifs.seekg(byteOffset);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < intCount; ++i)
    {
        int i;
        ifs >> i;
        output.push_back(i);
    }
}

...

std::vector<int> loadedInts;
appendInts("myfile", 600, 60, loadedInts);
```

Comment: Could you please fill in the line where you put the comment? I am not experienced with C++, and this is not the easiest task in the world.

Comment: Check the fread documentation, for example on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/.

Or again, use the C++ way with streams http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious, and will be looking myself after posting this, but what exactly is the behavior of a formatted extract `operator >>()` on an `ifstream` opened in *binary* mode?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of vector use integer array and pass poth file discriptor and the array pointer to function `read()`
as below

```
...
int my_integers[240];
read(m_infile, my_integers, 240, 600);
..
```

for more information about `read()` refer to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html